# Not replacing deleted config file /etc/default/burg?

Tags: boot, 16.04, grub2, burg

I uninstalled and purged BURG bootloader and all it's repositories and files but when I try to reinstall it, I get an error saying "Not replacing deleted config file /etc/default/burg" and when it shows that error, upon boot, my BURG has no themes and looks like GRUB. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

Purging the package is not enough: `ucf` (update configuration files) protects the files. One way to avoid this is to force `ucf` default action. I didn't had much luck with `confmiss` in `dpkg` options, so I've read the `ucf` documentation.

1. override the default `ucf` action, to create configuration if it doesn't already exists:

```
export UCF_FORCE_CONFFMISS=1
```

2. purge the package:

```
apt-get purge burg
```

3. reinstall the package:

```
apt-get install burg
```

4. set back the `ucf` default action:

```
export UCF_FORCE_CONFFMISS=
```

Side note: you can use `UCF_FORCE_CONFFNEW=1` to erase your configuration files, but use with caution.

Answer (score 1):

Since purging the package can cause all kinds of dependency problems, here's a script to pull the problems out of apt, purge ucf, then get the config files back. It's disgusting to have to do this.

This is `reinstall-purge-ucf`:

```
#!/bin/bash
PACKAGE=$1
apt-get install --reinstall $PACKAGE | grep 'Not replacing deleted config file' | awk '{print $6}' | tr -d '[$]' | tr -d '[\r]' |  xargs -t -n 1 ucf -p 
apt-get install --reinstall $PACKAGE
```

Now do, for example:

```
# ./reinstall-purge-ucf php7.4-json
ucf -p /etc/php/7.4/mods-available/json.ini
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/19.3 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
(Reading database ... 191911 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../php7.4-json_7.4.30-1+deb11u1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking php7.4-json (7.4.30-1+deb11u1) over (7.4.30-1+deb11u1) ...
Setting up php7.4-json (7.4.30-1+deb11u1) ...
Processing triggers for libapache2-mod-php7.4 (7.4.30-1+deb11u1) ...
Processing triggers for php7.4-fpm (7.4.30-1+deb11u1) ...
NOTICE: Not enabling PHP 7.4 FPM by default.
NOTICE: To enable PHP 7.4 FPM in Apache2 do:
NOTICE: a2enmod proxy_fcgi setenvif
NOTICE: a2enconf php7.4-fpm
NOTICE: You are seeing this message because you have apache2 package installed.
Processing triggers for php7.4-cli (7.4.30-1+deb11u1) ...
Processing triggers for php7.4-phpdbg (7.4.30-1+deb11u1) ...
```

And then the files we need are there.

Answer (score 0):

Purge the package,

Run `dpkg -P burg`

Reinstall

Comment: When I do that and run 'sudo dpkg -P burg', it says 'dpkg: warning: ignoring request to remove burg which isn't installed'.

Comment: And it didn't work :/

Answer (score 0):

With `apt`, you have to add the parameter `--reinstall` like this:

```
sudo apt -y --reinstall install burg
```

It will reinstall deleted config files.
I don't know if `apt` exists in `16.04`.

Comment: Nope, `apt install --reinstall fusioninventory-agent` still refuses to reinstall the files purged when I purged the package earlier. This is on Ubuntu 20.04.